# Route to generic Razor page only if physical resource doesn't exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am a front-end dev and don't know a lot about C#. I have been dabbling in Razor views so I can sort-of make my way around it. I am developing a project that might require some C# routing and I can't get it working **(I think this is due to my limited understanding)**.

We built a website that contains a mix of static resources (physical .cshtml pages) and then also content that is stored in a database. All the links to these content pieces are generated via handlebars templates so I cannot use Razor within my templates (that I know of). The database content needs to use **`page.cshtml`**, which should then also be routed to remove *page* from the URL.

So in essence, when you hit `http://www.example.com/my-page` it should check if **`my-page.cshtml`** exists, else use `http://www.example.com/page/my-page` rewritten as `http://www.example.com/my-page`.

I'm trying to use this but it isn't working:

```
using System.Web.Routing;

public class Routes
{
   void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
   {
    routes.MapPageRoute("Deals",
        "/{page}", "~/page.cshtml");
   }
}
```

Is this possible using only Razor? I have tried routing via **C# RouteConfig** but the project is using V4 of .NET so attribute routing doesn't work. I also can't use a catchall route as there are some pages that are within directories.

Or is my only option to explicitly state a link to `/page/` in the DB and do IIS rewrites?

My other option is to always hit **`page.cshtml`** and if it can't find the content in my DB, it loads in **`my-page.cshtml`** as a partial. But then what happens if someone types `http://www.example.com/my-page` into the address bar?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your my-page.cshtml file exist in your controller

```
 string myFile = Server.MapPath("path to my-page.cshtml");

 if(File.Exists(myFile))
 {   
    return View("path to my-page.cshtml"); 
 }

else
{
   //from db
}
```

ps: you need to use System.IO in your controller